# Why does the Azure Cognitive Search Python SDK not return @search.answers arraya when the API does?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

I am having an issue with the beta version of the Azure Cognitive Search Python SDK "[azure-search-documents 11.3.0b6](https://pypi.org/project/azure-search-documents/11.3.0b6/)" which can be used to query an Azure Cognitive Search index and supply results including relevant content and a brief passage of text that can answer the query if it's formatted as a question.

When using POSTMAN to query the API directly, it supplies an answer within an array called "@search.answers" but when using the same arguments and query, I don't see an answer in the results. Is there a known issue with the SDK since it's beta or does someone have a working version that they can show me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Index definition

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://<servicename>.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexes/$entity",
"@odata.etag": "\"0x8DBC386F9BFC9DA\"",
"name": "<indexname>",
"defaultScoringProfile": null,
"fields": [
    {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "searchable": false,
        "filterable": true,
        "retrievable": true,
        "sortable": true,
        "facetable": true,
        "key": true,
        "indexAnalyzer": null,
        "searchAnalyzer": null,
        "analyzer": null,
        "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
        "name": "metadata_spo_item_name",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "searchable": true,
        "filterable": true,
        "retrievable": true,
        "sortable": true,
        "facetable": false,
        "key": false,
        "indexAnalyzer": null,
        "searchAnalyzer": null,
        "analyzer": null,
        "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
        "name": "metadata_spo_item_path",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "searchable": false,
        "filterable": false,
        "retrievable": true,
        "sortable": false,
        "facetable": false,
        "key": false,
        "indexAnalyzer": null,
        "searchAnalyzer": null,
        "analyzer": null,
        "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
        "name": "metadata_spo_item_content_type",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "searchable": false,
        "filterable": true,
        "retrievable": true,
        "sortable": false,
        "facetable": true,
        "key": false,
        "indexAnalyzer": null,
        "searchAnalyzer": null,
        "analyzer": null,
        "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
        "name": "metadata_spo_item_last_modified",
        "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset",
        "searchable": false,
        "filterable": false,
        "retrievable": true,
        "sortable": true,
        "facetable": false,
        "key": false,
        "indexAnalyzer": null,
        "searchAnalyzer": null,
        "analyzer": null,
        "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
        "name": "metadata_spo_item_size",
        "type": "Edm.Int64",
        "searchable": false,
        "filterable": false,
        "retrievable": true,
        "sortable": false,
        "facetable": false,
        "key": false,
        "indexAnalyzer": null,
        "searchAnalyzer": null,
        "analyzer": null,
        "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
        "name": "metadata_spo_item_weburi",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "searchable": true,
        "filterable": false,
        "retrievable": true,
        "sortable": false,
        "facetable": false,
        "key": false,
        "indexAnalyzer": null,
        "searchAnalyzer": null,
        "analyzer": null,
        "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
        "name": "content",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "searchable": true,
        "filterable": false,
        "retrievable": true,
        "sortable": false,
        "facetable": false,
        "key": false,
        "indexAnalyzer": null,
        "searchAnalyzer": null,
        "analyzer": null,
        "synonymMaps": []
    }
],
"scoringProfiles": [],
"corsOptions": null,
"suggesters": [
    {
        "name": "sg",
        "searchMode": "analyzingInfixMatching",
        "sourceFields": [
            "metadata_spo_item_name"
        ]
    }
],
"analyzers": [],
"tokenizers": [],
"tokenFilters": [],
"charFilters": [],
"encryptionKey": null,
"similarity": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.BM25Similarity",
    "k1": null,
    "b": null
}
```

}

POSTMAN API config and results
[image: Screenshot of POSTMAN body and results]

Python code and results

```
import os

# load classes from libraries
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from typing import cast
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.search.documents import SearchClient
load_dotenv()

# Load the environment variables
index_name = cast(str, os.getenv("SEARCH_INDEX_NAME"))
endpoint_name = cast(str, os.getenv("SEARCH_ENDPOINT"))
key = cast(str, os.getenv("SEARCH_API_KEY"))

# search function configured with semanatic search configuration
def search(event=None):
    search_query = "what is a service that provides site recovery"
    search_client = SearchClient(endpoint_name, index_name, AzureKeyCredential(key))
    results = search_client.search(
          search_text=search_query,
          query_speller="lexicon",
          query_type="semantic",
          semantic_configuration_name="Pilot Semantic",
          query_answer="extractive",
          query_answer_count=1,
          query_caption="extractive",
          query_caption_highlight=True,
          query_language="en-us",
          search_mode="any",
          include_total_count=True,
          top=1,
          select="metadata_spo_item_name"
    )
    for result in results:
        #content = result["content"]
        #truncated_content = (content[:300] + '..') if len(content) > 100 else content
        #print(truncated_content)
        print(result)
  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    search()
```

[image: Screenshot of Python code and results]

Comment: can you update the question with the index definition you have used, that can help in reproduce the issue?

Comment: @RishabhM I've updated the question to include the index definition. This is for SharePoint as a datasource which is in preview and you must request access from Microsoft if you have not done so already. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `@search.answers` with python SDK, you can use `results.get_answers()` with your results output.

Below is sample code snippet to get the `text and highlight` from answers:

```py
semantic_answers = results.get_answers()
for answer in semantic_answers:
    if answer.highlights:
        print(f"Semantic Answer: {answer.highlights}")
    else:
        print(f"Semantic Answer: {answer.text}")
    print(f"Semantic Answer Score: {answer.score}\n")
```

I have used the latest beta version: [azure-search-documents 11.4.0b8](https://pypi.org/project/azure-search-documents/11.4.0b8/)

With the above SDK version and code, I was able to get required results.
[image]

For more details you can check this [sample notebook.](https://github.com/Azure/cognitive-search-vector-pr/blob/main/demo-python/code/azure-search-vector-python-sample.ipynb)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was able to see the return of the '@search.captions' block after updating the SDK to the higher beta version. I then added your semantic answers code block to my existing function and now get the full output that I was looking for. You are a gem!